# How can store sqlplus query in a file in formatted manner and display it to console up vote

Tags: shell, sqlplus

I am trying to write a script which will connect to database and store the query output in a file in formatted manner

My expected file would be something like below:

```
LAST                         MONTHLY
NAME                          SALARY  COMMISSION
------------------------- ----------  ----------
Russell                        14000         .4
Partners                       13500         .3
Errazuriz                      12000         .3
Cambrault                      11000         .3
Zlotkey                        10500         .2
```

So far I have tried this.

```
sqlplus user/password@(TNS Entry) << EOF
SET head OFF;
SET feed OFF;
SET trimspool ON;
SET linesize 32767;
SET pagesize 32767;
SET echo OFF;
SET termout OFF;
SET verify OFF;
SET NEWPAGE NONE;
SET verify off;
spool file_name.csv
select * from Customer;
spool off

EXIT;
EOF
```

I am trying to display CSV file to console. But, it is not in a formatted style.

How can i achieve this ?

Comment: How is it not in a formatted style?

Answer (score 0):

You need to add in the , seperator yourself e.g.

```
sqlplus user/password@(TNS Entry) << EOF
SET head OFF;
SET feed OFF;
SET trimspool ON;
SET linesize 32767;
SET pagesize 32767;
SET echo OFF;
SET termout OFF;
SET verify OFF;
SET NEWPAGE NONE;
SET verify off;
spool file_name.csv
select last_name  || ',' || monthly_salary || ',' || commission from customer;
spool off

EXIT;
EOF
```

or you can add

```
set colsep ,
```

to your script instead.